# Knockout textbox hasfocus requires two click to leave focus after typing in some text

Tags: knockout.js

I have hasfocus databind on a textbox and after typing some text then clicking on another textbox the focus does not change until you click again.  It seems like the first click doesn't change focus regardless of where you click.

Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates this http://jsfiddle.net/9LuJy/1/.

Here is the viewmodels that cause this problem.

```
var viewmodel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.fields = ko.observableArray();
    self.fields.push(new Field());
}

var Field = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.isFocus = ko.observable(false);
    self.textValue = ko.observable();
}
```

and here is the html

```
<div data-bind="foreach: fields">
    <input type="text" data-bind="hasfocus: isFocus, value: textValue" />
</div>

<input type="text" />
```

I expect it may be do to updating the observable after typing so maybe need some sort of delay?

Comment: Looking at some related [issue commentary](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/698) provides some details regarding this issue. Upgrading to v2.3 seems to fix the problem. I only noticed the problem in Chrome and adding a `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` also seemed to fix it.

Comment: @Origineil I think you should create an answer from your comment.  It was a known issue fixed in v2.3

Comment: It solves your problem by just upgrade from knockout 2.2.1 to 3.x.x.

Comment: @Origineil adding the valueUpdate seems to fix my issue.  I am at a point where I can't update knockout currently so that was not an option.  If you post your comment as an answer I will mark it is the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Known Issue fixed in V2.3

Out of Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Chrome, I only noticed the issue in Chrome. Taking into consideration the version of [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/index.html) used in the fiddle(`2.2.1`), I found [this commentary](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/698) related to the behavior described. Upgrading versions will fix the issue.

**Alternate Solution**

If upgrading versions is not a viable option, an alternative to consider is the addition of `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'`.